# JSON.stringify sends empty object

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I decided to stop using jQuery so I'm converting everything to pure JavaScript.

I have this `ajax` call and I want to send the last part of the url to the php server, but `JSON.stringify()` sends an`empty object` in the server.

Why is this happening?

AJAX call:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

ajax.open('get', 'ajax/autocomplete.php');
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
ajax.send(JSON.stringify({q: document.location.href.split('/').slice(-1)[0]}));
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    require_once '../../private/core/init.php';
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    print_r($_GET);//empty

    $data = new AUTOCOMPLETE($_GET['q']);
    echo json_encode($data->data());
?>
```

and I get this error: `Undefined index: q`

Comment: I don't think you should send a request entity with a GET request. Do a POST or use a query parameter (`?q=......`).

Comment: But I will get data. not write or update. @Thilo

Comment: The parameter data can only be sent with POST requests. data will not be placed inside the request body if any other request method is used. [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Thanks it works @Thilo

Comment: Why on earth would you stop using jQuery?

Comment: for performance, speed and one less library to load. @jjwdesign

Comment: Use a CDN if performance is an issue. Libraries are there to make life easier. jQuery is so useful and fast, but maybe your situation requires it.

Comment: yeah but pure JS is way lot faster.... @jjwdesign

Comment: hey @Thilo the same problems occurs even when I do POST request. whats the problem?

Comment: get works fine with in URL params but post doesn't when I sent an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to suppress PHP errors with error_reporting(0); or validate the input data first with isset/empty or some other function that will suppress the PHP warnings. The warning output will make your JSON response data invalid to your javascript (jQuery or pure javascript).

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require_once '../../private/core/init.php';
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $data = new AUTOCOMPLETE($_GET['q']);
    echo json_encode($data->data());
}
?>
```

Comment: yeah but  the same problems occurs even when I do POST request. whats the problem? I still get an empty object even with POST